# Using variables to save a repetition field in FileMaker

Tags: filemaker, repeat

I got a part number field that have several repetitions. I want to use a variable to save this so that I can show all the descriptions of these parts in a different layout when user click a button. 
But I do not know how to use variable to save several values like that. And I do not know exactly how many repetitions for each part number.

Comment: Can you share a few examples of what the part number fields look like? Maybe add some pseudocode to describe what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I would suggest you rethink your strategy on two counts: **1.** Do not store data in repeating fields; use individual **records** in a related table instead. **2.** As much as possible, show data directly from the fields storing it. It is not at all clear why you need to "*show all the descriptions of these parts in a different layout*", but almost certainly using variables to "store" them is **not** the best way.

Comment: my part number is an editable file with more than 10 lines. When user input new part number, it will be in 1 line regard to 1 repetition. Now I want to capture all this repetition and save to variables so that I can use this variable to show the description of all these part in another layout. btw thank you for ur answer.

Comment: I am afraid we're not making any progress here. I suggest you learn about using a related table to store the part numbers. You will probably want to use a **portal** to display them - it's hard to tell for sure without knowing what "*another layout*" means.

Answer (score 0):

Although FileMaker allows for repetition fields and they have some valid behind-the-scenes uses for the database developer, they should NEVER be used for data. As pointed out by others, you should rethink you data structure.

That being said, you can capture the information in repeating fields by specifying which repetition you're interested in. If you have a repeating field named "partNumber" with 10 repetitions, then you can access each of the repetitions by:

```
partNumber[1]
partNumber[2]
.
.
.
partNumber[9]
partNumber[10]
```

Answer (score 0):

RepFieldToVar [calculation] =Let($$varName = List(RepeatingFieldName), "")

This puts all repetitions into a return-delimited value list in $$varName.

Incidentally, there are *_exceedingly rare_* instances where repeating fields are still useful. I've used them for grid-type schedule layouts that need stored values. But 99.98% of the time the other commenters are right, you can probably do it more efficiently with related records.

Comment: Repeating fields can be extremely useful, in *many* instances . Although in 99% of the time these will be repeating **calculation** fields.

Comment: I last used them (quite a while ago, I admit) for a user-facing instantly-updated schedule grid with both data entry and calculations, whereas calculations in related tables may not update until window refresh. It could have been done without repeating fields, but that would have required hundreds of nearly-identical calculations, which makes everybody sad.

But it's splitting hairs for sure. That's a very specialized, exceptional circumstance. And it was before script triggers, so today I could conceivably have circumvented the update problem, altho perhaps not w/o performance considerations.